# How can I evaluate this complex integral equation on Wolfram?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I need to evaluate the complex line integrals in the following equation:
$$g(z)=\frac{\int_0^z\zeta^{-5/6}(\zeta-1)^{-1/2}d\zeta}{\int_0^1\zeta^{-5/6}(\zeta-1)^{-1/2}d\zeta}.$$
Can someone advise me on how to evaluate this expression on Wolfram? For those interested in the background, the source of the above equation is
"[Conformal mapping between two right-angled triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362941/conformal-mapping-between-two-right-angled-triangles/362956#362956)". If not possible on Wolfram, is there an alternate means to evaluate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, Mathematica seems to have no trouble performing the integral directly:

[image: Integrals in Mathematica]

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't think it would be that straightforward :D

Comment: I would very much appreciate it if you could help me out with my latest post as well, as I do not have access to Mathematica.